# Graphing a hyperbola in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to graph a solution obtained through the quadratic formula in Matlab. Since it's obtained by the quadratic formula, there are two parts: plus and minus. The graph should be a hyperbola. How can I place the upper part and the bottom part on the same graph?

Comment: try plotting two lines the same color. One the top part, and one the bottom part. You can use the hold on command to plot more than one line on the same graph. There is probably a better way but it would work easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways. Let's say you want to plot the solution of `y^2 = x`, that is `y = ±sqrt(x)`:

1. You can plot the two parts with the same color using a plot once…

   ```
   x = 0:0.1:10;
   plot(x, sqrt(x), 'k', x, -sqrt(x), 'k')
   ```
2. …or twice:

   ```
    x = 0:0.1:10;
    plot(x, sqrt(x), 'k')
    hold on
    plot(x, -sqrt(x), 'k')
    hold off
   ```
3. Or you can plot everything in one go like you might draw it with a pen:

   ```
    x = [10:-0.1:0 0.1:0.1:10];
    y = [-sqrt(10:-0.1:0) sqrt(0.1:0.1:10)];
    plot(x, y)
   ```